# Who does "she" refer to in "She wasn’t the jealous type, but she’d always been curious, and Sabé rarely did anything first."?

Tags: pronouns, parsing, personal-pronouns

In *Star Wars: Queen's Shadow*, there is a conversation between Padmé and Sabé:

> “Do you like him enough?”, Padme said.
>
> “I don’t know,” Sabé said. “We’ve talked about it, so it’s not like I’m leading him on. And I warned him. A lot. And he’s known me, us, for a long time.”
>
> “You’re protecting him.” It wasn’t quite a question. As usual, they walked the line of their peculiar bond with perfect symmetry.
>
> “I don’t want to be callous,” Sabé said. “So in a way, I am protecting myself, too.”
>
> “I don’t know what I’d do,” Padmé said. “I’ve guarded my heart against everything for so long, always aware of the dynamics and the flow of power. I’ve been lucky to find so many people who understand that and give me that space. I’m afraid that if someone breaks through, I’ll let them, and it would be catastrophic.”
>
> “It’s not a reactor leak,” Sabé said.
>
> Padmé never spoke to her about matters of the heart, largely, Sabé suspected, out of respect for privacy. She wondered who Padmé was thinking of that made her do it now, or if Padmé was merely intrigued by the prospect of whatever she imagined Sabé was getting up to. **She wasn’t the jealous type, but she’d always been curious, and Sabé rarely did anything first**.
>
> “Maybe you should let someone break through a little bit,” Sabé suggested. “To see how it goes.”

Now I think that "she" in the bold sentence refers to Sabé herself, but due to the mentioning of "Sabé" in the same line, it seems to refer to Padmé! To which one of them "she" refers?

Comment: There seems to be a shift in writing style. Sabé seems to be the person saying all this. But that last sentence then is a bit odd. It would have been much clearer to have Sábe instead of she in that last sentence followed by the two she's.

Comment: The sentence is honestly just kind of clumsy. It's giving Padmé's history as an attempt to justify Sabé's guesses about her mental state in the previous sentence, but because the "jealousy" section is a non-sequitur it's very difficult to make that connection. The only way to really make it is to notice the mirroring between "intrigued" and "curious".

Comment: Even as a native speaker, I find it confusing to have a sentence start with "She" after just having named two different female characters in the previous clause.  I would have worded it "Padmé...she'd...Sabé" to clarify.

Comment: Yes it's confusing because the sentence starts with "She wondered" which is a co-reference to Sabé in the preceeding sentence. But in the middle of that sentence there's another co-reference "she imagined Sabé" where "she" is a co-reference to Padmé. So then the next She should really be another co-reference to Padme - but I think it's actually a co-reference to the following Sabé. Its poorly written and the bolded sentence should start with Sabe (or Padme if that was the intention, in which case it needs more editing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> She wasn’t the jealous type, but she’d always been curious, and Sabé rarely did anything first.

When we name someone *and then* use a pronoun, it usually refers to the same person. Subsequent uses of the same pronoun can usually be assumed to mean the same person, so long as nobody else has been named between times.

> **John** loves football and **he** plays whenever **he** can.

But in your example, the pronoun comes first *and then* Sabe is named. This is normally done to differentiate or 'switch' between persons who may share the same pronoun. So, it seems pretty clear that 'she' refers to Padme.

Comment: What you say is true but the narrator is Sabé, which then makes it odd.

Comment: @lambie Sabe is **not** the narrator. If she were, it would say "*I suspect*", and not "Sabé suspected". You're confusing the narrator with the 'narrative perspective'.

Comment: There is such a thing as third-person narration, and as such, she is the third-person narrator. You are describing: first-person narration.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, that's what you've confused it with. The narrator is a third person, neither Padme nor Sabe. The third-person exists outside of the events of the story.

Comment: What Is Third-Person Point Of View in Writing?
In third-person point of view, the author is narrating a story about the characters, referring to them by name, or using the third-person pronouns “he,” “she,” and “they.” The other points of view in writing are first person and second person. https://www.masterclass.com/articles/what-is-third-person-point-of-view-in-writing-how-to-write-in-third-person-narrative-voice-with-examples

Comment: @Lambie "In third-person point of view, _the author_ is _narrating_ a story" https://www.masterclass.com/articles/what-is-third-person-point-of-view-in-writing-how-to-write-in-third-person-narrative-voice-with-examples

Comment: @YonKuma The author is always narrating a story. Characters can't narrate themselves. I believe there is a SHIFT within the paragraph regarding the attributed speaker.

Comment: @Lambie First-person narration is literally defined by the conceit that a character is narrating a story about themself. Third-person narration is defined by the conceit that no character is narrating the story.

Comment: I had trouble getting my head around "second person narrative" in the context of actual "storytelling". But as it says [here,](https://prowritingaid.com/art/2332/second-person-point-of-view.aspx) *With second-person point of view, the writer addresses the reader using the pronoun "you". It forces the reader into the story, making them part of the action and complicit in events. **It is hard to sustain** over longer pieces of writing, which is one reason it is **rarely used in narrative texts**.* That's that settled, then.

Comment: Second person is a bit odd, because it can't be defined by the ostensible narrator of the story, unlike the other two. Instead, the narrator may or may not be a character in the story, but the defining conceit is that the reader is a character in the story.

Comment: @Lambie "*The author is always narrating a story*". Simply not true. Author and narrator have fundamental differences as terms. You should read *The Great Gatsby*.

Comment: @YonKuma The author is writing the story where the narrator narrates. So, the author is actually the narrator. In fact, regardeless of narration type, the author writes from point of view he chooses including first-person where he is not that person but narrates as if he were.

Comment: The author **creates** the narrator.

Comment: @Lambie Finally! And of course, one cannot create oneself.

Answer (score 1):

> Padmé never spoke to her about matters of the heart, largely, Sabé suspected, out of respect for privacy. She wondered who Padmé was thinking of that made her do it now, or if Padmé was merely intrigued by the prospect of whatever she imagined Sabé was getting up to. **She** wasn’t the jealous type, but she’d always been curious, and Sabé rarely did anything first.

In my opinion, although this passage is not a stunning example of clear writing, it doesn't make much sense for "She" here to refer anyone but Padmé.

The paragraph appears to be in what I've seen called 'third-person limited' narration: Sabé isn't the narrator, but the narrator seems to be describing Sabé's thoughts. The complication is that here, Sabé's thoughts are speculation about what Padmé thinks: "[Sabé] wondered who Padmé was thinking of [...] or if Padmé was merely intrigued [...]"

Then, the following sentence **explains** why Padmé might be intrigued: because Padmé "[ha]d always been curious, and Sabé rarely did anything first." The fact that Padmé "wasn’t the jealous type, but [ha]d always been curious" is part of Sabé's train of thought here. Because Padmé is not "the jealous type", Sabé expects that Padmé will not feel jealousy about the relationship between Sabé and the man that she is talking about, but Sabé thinks that Padmé might be curious about it.